My ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener is not working, how to make it work
I am developing route optimiser using timefold python but ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener is not running I also included print statement to check if it's running in background or not. I have used the code that was given in the tests folder in timefold_solver_python official repo.
link: https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver-python/blob/main/tests/test_vehicle_routing.py#L28
My code:
`class ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener(VariableListener):
    @staticmethod
    def calculate_arrival_time(customer: Optional['Customer'], previous_departure_time: Optional[datetime]) \
            -> datetime | None:
        if customer is None or previous_departure_time is None:
            return None
        return previous_departure_time + timedelta(seconds=customer.drivingTimeSecondsFromPreviousStandstill)

    def after_variable_changed(self, score_director: ScoreDirector, customer: 'Customer') -> None:
        print("b")
        if customer.vehicle is None:
            if customer.arrival_time is not None:
                score_director.before_variable_changed(customer, 'arrival_time')
                customer.arrival_time = None
                score_director.after_variable_changed(customer, 'arrival_time')
            return None
        previous_customer = customer.previous_customer
        departure_time = customer.vehicle.departure_time if previous_customer is None \
            else previous_customer.get_departure_time()
        next_customer = customer
        arrival_time = ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener.calculate_arrival_time(next_customer, departure_time)
        while next_customer is not None and next_customer.arrival_time != arrival_time:
            score_director.before_variable_changed(next_customer, 'arrival_time')
            next_customer.arrival_time = arrival_time
            score_director.after_variable_changed(next_customer, 'arrival_time')
            departure_time = next_customer.get_departure_time()
            next_customer = next_customer.next_customer
            arrival_time = ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener.calculate_arrival_time(next_customer, departure_time)


@planning_entity
class Customer(JsonDomainBase):
    id: Annotated[str, PlanningId]
    name: Optional[str] = None
    location: Annotated[Location, LocationSerializer, LocationValidator]
    ready_time: datetime
    due_time: datetime
    service_duration: timedelta
    demand: int
    vehicle: Annotated[Optional['Vehicle'], InverseRelationShadowVariable(
        source_variable_name='customers'), IdSerializer, VehicleValidator, Field(default=None)]
    previous_customer: Annotated[Optional['Customer'], PreviousElementShadowVariable(
        source_variable_name='customers'), IdSerializer, CustomerValidator, Field(default=None)]
    next_customer: Annotated[Optional['Customer'], NextElementShadowVariable(
        source_variable_name='customers'), IdSerializer, CustomerValidator, Field(default=None)]
    arrival_time: Annotated[Optional[datetime], ShadowVariable(
        variable_listener_class=ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener,
        source_variable_name='vehicle'), ShadowVariable(
        variable_listener_class=ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener,
        source_variable_name='previous_customer'), Field(default=None)]


I have tried to debug but nothing was printing, I want arrival time

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

We are aware of bugs that currently prevent the Timefold Solver for Python from processing variable listeners correctly. Without looking at your code, I will make a suggestion to wait for the next release of Timefold Solver for Python.

Hey @LukášPetrovický is there any work around that I can do or you can share any timeline for the update as timefold python is now merged with main timefold repo so, is there anything that I can do now. Thanks

Upgrade to Timefold Solver 1.13.0 or later, it supports this correctly now.
See the python vehicle routing quickstarts in timefold-quickstarts.
